# Managing space during localization

Tags: c#, wpf, string, localization

I am implementing a localization feature in my GUI window that will allow the user to change the language of the program at run-time. During the language changes the text in my program changes length, which sometimes causes the text to either interfere with another control, or run off of the page.

An Example (Text under the TextBox):

[image]

What is the best method to avoid the text running haywire when the length changes?

-So far I have tried `textWrapping` but I think it's probably a primitive solution.

-I discussed a possible solution with @Roy Dictus below, but more opinions or methods are definitely needed. I need to be able to make space for growing `strings` in my UI.

Answer (score 0):

What the "best" way is, is probably up for debate, but it's a good idea to come up with reasonable length limits for labels.

Build your UI with dummy labels ("XXXXX" instead of "Name" for instance) and see what acceptable length limits are. Best is to not do this per input field but to have an overall number, or perhaps have a few categories of labels/messages each with their own limits.

Then when you build your UI, test with the maximum limits (say you agree that a textbox label should be no more than 12 characters -- then in your development environment, put all textbox labels to "XXXXXXXXXXXX").

Then make sure that for every language you have translations for, you stay within those limits. If that is hard to do, use abbreviations where necessary.

Comment: So you're saying that I can set a maximum limit for each of my labels in my UI?

Comment: No, it's something to check for when you make or receive your translations. Define the standard, then check for it.

Comment: I guess then my questions would be, how exactly do I define the standard? -- and would the check have to be some kind of function?

Comment: *Build your UI with dummy labels ("XXXXX" instead of "Name" for instance) and see what acceptable length limits are.* And the check can be manual... When you ask a translator to create translations, tell him/her what the limits are, and verify yourself when you receive the translated texts that these limits are respected.

Comment: Okay, I gotcha. What I'm thinking right now is adding new line indicators into the xaml of the translated strings. Is that on the right track? (right now I'm serving as the translator)

Comment: You can do that, sure.

Comment: If I do that and I don't have space below it, the string on the new line doesn't get displayed. What do I do in that case?

Comment: Of course you would only allow it in case you do have space below. Or you can make a point to always have enough space available. It's up to you to decide, as long as you are consistent.